# awk for loop if big than a number print

Tags: awk

file format: count ip
cat file.txt

```
2  11.22.33.33
10 33.33.44.55
```

I want to print lines which $1 > $MAX

```
MAX=10
cat $ip_file | awk '{counts[$1]++} END{ for (ip in counts) if ($(counts[ip]) > "'${MAX}'" )  print counts[ip] " " ip  }
```

the scrip above does not work, please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v max=$MAX '{counts[$1]++} END {for(ip in counts) if(counts[ip]>max) print counts[ip], ip}' ip_file
```

Use `-v max=$MAX` to get the value of `$MAX` to awk. Also, no need to abuse the cat, just put the `ip_file` after the command.